# Performing "grep" on multiple *.tar files and *.tgz

Tags: unix, terminal, grep

I have a directory of about 10 files with *.tar extension.

The 10 files have the following file name pattern.

```
File001.tar
File002.tar
File003.tar
..
File010.tar
```

Is there a way I can grep all 10 files for "Error" passing a wildcard to the filename in a terminal. How do I do this and also how would I do this if all the files have the extension "*.tgz" ?

Comment: A tarfile can contain many other files... do you mean you want to know the names of the files within the tarfile that contain the word "Error"? Or do you mean you want to know if any of your tarfiles contain a file whose name contains the word "Error"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should make it:

```
grep "Error" /your_dir/*tar
```

Or also

```
grep --include="*tar" "Error" /your_dir/*
```

---

For `tgz` files, use [`zgrep`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_zgrep.htm).

```
zgrep "Error" /your_dir/*tgz
```

Or also

```
grep --include="*tgz" "Error" /your_dir/*
```

Comment: When I do this:
grep "Error" /your_dir/*tar

I get this in my output:

Binary file /your_dir/File001.tar matches
Binary file /your_dir/File002.tar matches
Binary file /your_dir/File003.tar matches
...
Binary file /your_dir/File004.tar matches


I'm expecting it to return the lines where it shows my "Error" ? Is this right?

Comment: Uhms, makes sense because *tar files are also compressed. You have two options: `tar xvf *.tar -O | grep "Error"` or directly `zgrep "Error" *tar`. Could you indicate how it works, because I am not sure if `zgrep` also works for tar files.

Answer (score 0):

use zgrep AND wildcard

```
zgrep "Error" /path/File*.tar
```

you can use wildcard to grep both in tar and tgz

```
zgrep "Error" /path/File*.t*
```

if the output is large, use "more":

```
zgrep "Error" /path/File*.t* | more
```